# Scaling a dataset in matplotlib on x and y axis relative to another dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, data-science

I am trying to scale two different sets of data to be visually equivalent.

*Green* data set has extreme Y values and significantly more data points. Hence *Orange* data set falls flat and short.

What functions exist that allow me to scale them equivalently with one another?

***Future viewers**: 'MinMax normalization' is one method as mentioned by the responses.

[image: Issue]

Comment: I would first take the range `[0, 20000]`, then take the maximum value in this range for the two datasets and scale both with this value. Another option is to scale them individually for their respective maximum values. If you want to do this you have methods in **scikit-learn**, e.g. [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to scale them X-Axis wise so the orange line is as long as the green (even though there are less data points for orange)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by squeezing the values between 0 and 1.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the green and orange data sets
green_data = np.random.normal(50, 10, 100)
orange_data = np.random.normal(25, 5, 10)

# Normalize the data sets using min-max scaling
green_data_normalized = (green_data - np.min(green_data)) / (np.max(green_data) - np.min(green_data))
orange_data_normalized = (orange_data - np.min(orange_data)) / (np.max(orange_data) - np.min(orange_data))

# Plot the normalized data sets
plt.plot(green_data_normalized, label='Green Data')
plt.plot(orange_data_normalized, label='Orange Data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: normalized graphs]

Edit: If you want to be able to get the orange values to have the same x-width as your green values, you can draw a straight line between each point, and use the midpoint to figure out what data point should go in between. This will widen the line by creating more data points, `numpy` has this built in with [np.interp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) (short for *interpolate*).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the green and orange data sets
green_data = np.random.normal(50, 10, 100)
orange_data = np.random.normal(25, 5, 10)

# Define the x-values for the original and extended orange data
x_orange_original = np.linspace(0, 1, len(orange_data))
x_orange_extended = np.linspace(0, 1, len(green_data))

# Interpolate the orange data to extend it
orange_data_extended = np.interp(x_orange_extended, x_orange_original, orange_data)

# Normalize the data sets using min-max scaling
green_data_normalized = (green_data - np.min(green_data)) / (np.max(green_data) - np.min(green_data))
orange_data_normalized = (orange_data_extended - np.min(orange_data_extended)) / (np.max(orange_data_extended) - np.min(orange_data_extended))

# Plot the normalized data sets
plt.plot(green_data_normalized, label='Green Data')
plt.plot(orange_data_normalized, label='Orange Data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you! Is there also a way to extend orange so it reaches just as far as green?

Comment: @MarkThomas No problem! I have edited my answer to include the answer to that.

Comment: Thank you! That's much easier than what I was about to do. Somehow missed this when reading documentation - perfect!